# ctypes ReadProcessMemory Python. Не считываются данные из массива С++

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes, pywin32

Всем привет! В процессе выполнения задачи столкнулся с проблемой считывания данных на Python из массива С++. Есть заданный массив и выделен его адрес:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()                          
{            
char numbers [] = { '1', '2', '3', '4' };       

int i = 0;
while(i < 4)
{
    std::cout << numbers[i] << std::endl;
    i++;
}

std::cout << std::addressof(numbers) << std::endl; 
std::cout << sizeof(numbers) << std::endl; 

std::getchar();
return 0;                       
}
```

Пример кода считывания на Python:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *
import win32ui, win32process, win32gui

PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF

HWND = win32gui.FindWindowEx(None, None, None,'simple-prog')
pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(HWND)[1]
OpenProcess = windll.kernel32.OpenProcess#(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,False,pid)
ReadProcessMemory = windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory
WriteProcessMemory = windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory

address = 0x0096F7CC
buffer = create_string_buffer(4)
bufferSize = (sizeof(buffer))
bytesRead = c_ulong(0)

print('HWND: ',HWND)
print('pid: ',pid)
print('buffer: ',buffer)
print('bufferSize: ',bufferSize)

processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)

if ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, address, buffer, bufferSize, byref(bytesRead)):
    print("Success:", buffer)
else:
    print("Failed.")

buffer = input('Записать данные: ')

if WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, address, buffer, bufferSize, byref(bytesRead)):
    print("Success:", buffer)
else:
    print("Failed.")
```

Мне нужно считать данные из массива и записать новые. Не могу разобраться, как правильно это сделать. Проблема на стороне скрипта Python.

Вот что выводит Python при считывании:

```
HWND:  4327514
pid:  9688
buffer:  <ctypes.c_char_Array_4 object at 0x02E42F80>
bufferSize:  4
Failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо было указать символьный тип контейнера (23 строка кода) модуля ctypes. В данном случае это выглядит так:

```
bytesRead = c_char(0)
```